# jQuery Mobile - Disable multiple select menu label changes - count bubble

Tags: jquery-mobile

When using a selection menu with the option for multiple select, jquery changes the menu's label based on the selected elements.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html

See this fiddle.  When user selects shipping options, the selected elements show in the menu's label.

http://jsfiddle.net/VEYjV/3/

How can I disable this feature and force the menu to keep the label I've associated with it (i.e. Choose options)?  How can I disable the count bubble feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to disable these features by hacking into the jquery.mobile lib.

I disabled the setButtonText and setButtonCount funcions when called from the refresh

```
refresh: function() {
    //this.setButtonText();
    //this.setButtonCount();
},
```

Comment: How did you catch the refresh function of select menu?

Comment: I was really just looking for where the setButtonText and setButtonCount were called.  That is why I commented them out of the lib